# Universal central extensions as a solution to lifting projective representations of the Galilei group

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, group-theory, representation-theory

Looking for an answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/757691/, [here](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Elandsman/Nesta.pdf)

I came across the notion of universal central extensions, let me call this **definition 1**:

> The group $G^{\star}=\mathbb{R}^{N} \times_{\xi^{ \star}}
>  \widetilde{G}$ defined as a central extension of the universal cover
> $\widetilde{G}$ by $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, i.e. as the product manifold
> $\mathbb{R}^{N} \times \widetilde{G}$ endowed with the operation
> \begin{equation} (a,x)(b,x)=(a+b+\xi^{\star}(x,y),xy), \end{equation}
> for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $x,y \in \widetilde{G}$, is called
> the **universal central extenson** of $G$. Given the covering map
> $\widetilde{p}:\widetilde{G} \to G$, we define the *universal covering
> map* in an obvious way \begin{equation} p^{\star}:G^{\star} \to G;\quad
>  (a,x) \mapsto \widetilde{p}(x). \end{equation}

However, in mathematical texts, a universal central extension is defined as a central extension, through which every other central extension factors uniquely. Let me refer to this as **definition 2**.

My question is: are **definition  1** and **definition 2** equivalent, namely: is it true that $1 \implies 2$ and $2 \implies 1$?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: You mean I should rewrite the statement itself? Sorry, I'm new to actively using SE.

Comment: Yes. Pictures of text aren't user friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I edited it. Do you perhaps know how to write something like \begin{defintion}\end{definition} on stackexchange?

Comment: The link is dead. Please update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that "universal" in the context of central extensions can mean different things when used by different authors, and that in contrast to other "universal" constructions in mathematics, the universal central extension for $\mathrm{U}(1)$-extensions may not be unique. A paper that discusses this in detail is Raghunathan's [*"Universal Central Extensions"*](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0129055X94000110), itself the appendix to the equally worthwhile [*"Symmetries and Quantization: Structure of the State Space"*](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0129055X94000109) by Divakaran.

As for the construction in the question, it is meant to be universal in the following sense: For every $\mathrm{U}(1)$-extension $e_\mu : G_\mu \to G$ with $\mu\in H^2(G,\mathrm{U}(1))$ classifying the extension, there is a preimage $\chi_\mu\in \hat{K}$ for $K = \ker(p^\ast) \cong \mathbb{R}^N \times\pi_1(G)$ (theorem 6.8 in the paper by Nesta) and so we get a map
$$q_\mu : G^\ast = \mathbb{R}^N\times_{\xi^\ast} \tilde{G} \to \mathrm{U}(1)\times_\mu G \cong G_\mu, (x,g)\mapsto (\chi_\mu(x), \pi(g))$$
with $p^\ast = q_\mu \circ e_\mu$, i.e. $p^\ast : G^\ast \to G$ factors through every $\mathrm{U}(1)$-extension $e_\mu$. The map $q_\mu$ is unique exactly when the morphism $\hat{K}\to H^2(G,\mathrm{U}(1))$ from theorem 6.8 is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! The paper by Divakaran seems a really good resource.